# Showing $\lim_{n\to \infty} (n-1)^k-n^k=0$ for $0 < k <1$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} (n-1)^k-n^k=0$  for $0 < k <1$.
>
> Use the fact that: $0 \le (n-1)^k-n^k = n^k((1-\frac 1 {n})^k-1)$

I'm staring at this problem clueless for some time now, I don't see how squeezing would work, using the limit definition with epsilon get me to a dead end as well... Any hints please?

**Note: no Taylor, LHR, integrals or derivatives.**

Comment: Can you use l'Hospital's rule?

Comment: how do you define $n^k$ for $0<k<1$?

Comment: Well @kuhaku, then it is going to be, apparently, one hell of calculations, as you can use almost nothing that could, probably, make this thing "softer". For one, I've no idea how to attack it just like that. Good luck, it's an interesting question.

Comment: @Lukas I think we define it as the kth root of n.

Comment: well actually, to define $n^k$ you have to use some sort of infinite series expansion, at least I can't think of another way.

Comment: Can you please share your source for this question ? I'm looking for a good place to practice such problems.

Comment: @SrinivasK it's from where I study, I know that we don't study math at a "pure math" level so most of the problems we get are a lot more simple than that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of a sequence - Apostol 10.22 #1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71911/limit-of-a-sequence-apostol-10-22-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have $1 > (1-\frac{1}{n})^{k} > (1-1/n)$ so that $|1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}| \leqslant  \frac{1}{n}$ and $|n^{k}(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k})| \leqslant |n^{k-1}|$.

But indeed $n^{k-1}\rightarrow 0$ so you can apply your squeezing theorem, since, as pointed out in the question, $(n-1)^{k}-n^{k}=n^{k}((1-1/n)^{k}-1)$.

I don't know where you got this problem but I find it to be a really good one. Taylor, integrals, derivatives, all ways of killing flies with atomic bombs.

Comment: So if you multiplied this $|1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}| \leqslant  \frac{1}{n}$ by $n^k$, where did the $1$ go?

Comment: Can you please explain the process for getting the last inequality? Let $w=(1 - 1/n )^k$. Then we have $|1-w|< 1/n$. From here , how did you get :  $|w|< 1/n$ ?

Comment: @Srinivas K I'm sorry I forgot to write down the $1$ in my post, I'll correct that.

Comment: I think I'm missing some basic point here. Can you please explain the next step for applying the squeeze theorem ? Is this correct :$n^k (( 1 - 1/n )^k - 1) < |n^k (1-( 1 - 1/n )^k )|< |n^{k-1}|   -> 0 $ ?

Comment: @Srinivas K What we proved is that $|(n-1)^{k}-n^{k}|=|n^{k}(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k})|<|n^{k-1}|$. So $0<|(n-1)^{k}-n^{k}|<|n^{k-1}|$, by squeeze theorem $|(n-1)^{k}-n^{k}|\rightarrow 0$, which implies that $(n-1)^{k}-n^{k}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I used an absolute value to write things faster and not get annoyed by sign questions, but if you prefer you can also prove $0>((n-1)^{k}-n^{k})>-n^{k-1}$ and then apply squeeze theorem.

Comment: Going from this step $1 > (1-\frac{1}{n})^{k} > (1-1/n)$ to $|1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}| \leqslant  \frac{1}{n}$. Shoudln't be: $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k} > 1- \frac 1 n$ then $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k} < \frac 1 n$?

Comment: No, $a>b>c$ implies $a-c > a-b$ so here with $a=1,b=(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}, c= (1-\frac{1}{n})$ you get $\frac{1}{n} > 1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k}$. I see you accepted the answer so you probably got that by yourself !